# Installing Mathematica on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: software-installation, sh, mathematica

How do I install using a `.sh` file on Ubuntu 15.10.

I'm specifically trying to install Wolfram Mathematica.

The file I'm wanting to use is `Mathematica_10.4.1.sh`

Comment: You can't install a shell script, but you can run it by doing `sh ./Mathematica_10.4.1.sh`

Comment: Just curious: why are you using Ubuntu 15.10? This hasn't been supported for 3 years now.

Answer (score 1):

Just type in terminal

```
sh Mathematica_10.4.1.sh
```

or again in terminal do

```
chmod +x Mathematica_10.4.1.sh
./Mathematica_10.4.1.sh
```

Comment: You do not need `sudo` to run `chmod`, if  you own the file. And there is no need for root to own the file.

Comment: I tried first order : sh Mathematica_10.4.1.sh, and it s running .......****** in this mode : .Enter the installation directory, or press ENTER to select
/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/10.4:
> su

Create directory (y/n)?
> y

Now installing...

[*****************************************************************************]

..but  I don `t know the activation way? is there any especially order such as Windows

Comment: @ASEMANEH4 I don't understand what are you saying in the comment. please elaborate

Comment: There's detailed instruction at http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12453

Comment: installation is completed, but my question is about activation key or other way to starting use Mathematica.

Comment: get a trial key from here. https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/trial/

Comment: @ASEMANEH4 "my question is about activation key or other way to starting use Mathematica" Are you asking how to bypass the activation?

Comment: yes , as you know in Window we have an ID & pass .... how to bypass this here ? it is same as Windows?

Comment: @ASEMANEH4 you need to put the MathID in these directories: `~/.Mathematica/Licensing/mathpass` `/usr/share/Mathematica/Licensing/mathpass`. _Maybe only one's needed but I'm not sure which one._ ..then enter your password normally

Answer (score 0):

The new Wolfram Mathematica install (v11.3, May 2018) is done by a shell script.

[How do I install Mathematica on Linux?](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12453)  (support.wolfram.com)

Excerpt:

> The Mathematica installer for Linux is a bash script that is run in
>   the Linux terminal. If you’re not familiar with the terminal, please
>   read a brief guide on how to use the terminal. The setup is an
>   easy-to-follow dialog. Please follow the corresponding instructions
>   for installing from a downloaded script or from a DVD or USB drive.

```
cd ~/Desktop
sudo bash installer.sh
```